# Refer to ID below in XML layout

Tags: android, xml, layout

In my XML layout, I have among other things two `EditText` elements and a few buttons. XML looks like this (most things removed, only relevant pieces left)

```
<RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/entry_id">

        <Button
             android:id="@+id/btn_select"
             layout_alignParentRight="true" />

        <EditText
             android:id="@+id/txt_id"
             android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn_select"
             anddroid:nextFocusDown="@id/txt_extras" />

        <Button
             android:id="@+id/btn_quality"
             android:layout_below="txt_id" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_extras"
        android:layout_below="@id/entry_id" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This produces a layout sort of like this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
|+---------------------------------------------+|
||                                             ||
||  +----------------------+  +-------------+  ||
||  | First text field     |  | Button      |  ||
||  +----------------------+  +-------------+  ||
||                                             ||
||  +----------------+                         ||
||  | Another button |                         ||
||  +----------------+                         ||
||                                             ||
|+---------------------------------------------+|
|                                               |
| +-------------------------------------------+ |
| | Second text field                         | |
| +-------------------------------------------+ |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Note that this is not the entire layout, there are a lot more different views in it, but I'm only concerned with these ones.  The reason `RelativeLayout`s are used is because they actually make it possible to lay out views in the way that the client wants.

Now, I need to define the block with the first text and buttons before defining the second text so that I could specify that the second text is below that block.  However then I get an error in the first text field because I'm referring to the second text field in the `nextFocusDown` attribute, because the second text field is not defined yet. This becomes catch 22.  Is there any way to make eclipse/lint/whatever understand that the field it's complaining about not being there *is* actually there, just a few lines below?  That is, is it possible to make it look at the file holistically, as a whole, and not line-by-line?

Alternatively, is there any other way to specify that I want the focus to go to the second text field and not to the second button when "next" is pressed on the soft keyboard?

Comment: Is it an actual error you are getting or just a Lint warning? Does the project compile?

Comment: change anddroid:nextFocusDown="@id/txt_extras" to anddroid:nextFocusDown="@+id/txt_extras"

Comment: @Squonk It's an actual error.  The project does not compile.

Comment: @Leonidos Ok, the error is not shown any more.  I'll need to write a bit more code before I can test it though, so I'll get back to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
anddroid:nextFocusDown="@id/txt_extras"
```

The above line should be changed to:

```
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/txt_extras"
```

As you can see in the [input events documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html#HandlingFocus), they use `@+id` for `nextFocus*`, even if the ID is already defined.

If you still get an error, you may have to change `android:id="@+id/txt_extras"` to `android:id="@id/txt_extras"` (removing the `+` sign), but this shouldn't be necessary.